# IronCache as Memcached server on PHP returns code 47 (?)

Tags: php, memcached, iron.io

When following the [IronCache guide](http://dev.iron.io/cache/reference/memcache/), I receive <strike>a misterious</strike> code 47 trying to set any key - including the requested `oauth` token.

<strike>This code is not present in the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php#95793).
Is this related to the fact IronCache only supports the text protocol? If yes, how would we use IronCache as a Memcached server in PHP?</strike>

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9042985/102960), 47 means `MEMCACHED_SERVER_TEMPORARILY_DISABLED`. So what? IronCache advertises Memcache support but actually their servers are not even working?
This would not be related to their text-only protocol, since [by default PHP uses the text protocol](https://www.php.net/manual/en/memcached.constants.php#memcached.constants.opt-binary-protocol). However, I did tested forcing `Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL` to `false`, but it still made no differen

```
$cache = new Memcached;
$cache->addServer('cache-aws-us-east-1.iron.io', 11211);
$cache->set('oauth', getenv('IRON_CACHE_TOKEN').' '.getenv('IRON_CACHE_PROJECT_ID').' general', 0);
}
var_dump($cache->getResultCode()); //47 ?!
```

Comment: btw, nice to see they suggest searching for tags here in SO that don't even exist, like `ironcache`

Comment: This was a pet project. If it went fine, I would use IronCache in my production system as well, as it has a bigger space on Heroku. Sadly, it seems just a piece of junk, at least in PHPland. Moved to MemcachedCloud.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the port 80 instead of 11211, i.e. replace

```
$cache->addServer('cache-aws-us-east-1.iron.io', 11211);
```

with

```
$cache->addServer('cache-aws-us-east-1.iron.io', 80);
```